# What does /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/of_node/efficiency file contains

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-kernel

What does /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/of_node/efficiency  file contains and how to parse the contents in human readable form.

Taken the hex dump and got

```
xxd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/of_node/efficiency                                                                                                                                                                                          
00000000: 0000 0466 ...f
```

Comment: I think you might get better response at [android.se].

Comment: Probably related: [What's of_node parameter in the struct device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22783154/295004)